# Is there any methods or possibilities to hide network request raised by the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created login and signup end-points on node-js, using react-js created necessary form and field for login and signup and on submit of form, posting the data to the server and getting a proper response. And under network section inside the browser, users can able to see the endpoint and the data ( username and password ) provided by the user.

Is there any possibility to hide the request and the data from the users. In the same way, I want to hide a few API requests from the client aprt from login and signup. Like profile update, organization details and profile create/update/delete, permission create/update/delete

FYI kindly access the link provided below :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bbrsOQlE4159CMm2P0ktzNf6SfCd3h0F

Comment: I am not but may be its nt possible. What u ca do u can do some security check to ur certain endpint. Only logged in user can hit those endpoint. 
and For login when u take user password u should encrypt it u can jwt for those things

Comment: No.  You cannot prevent people from seeing via the developer tools what you send.  This is the nature of the browser.  They can also see what you send with free packet sniffers installed on the local computer or a proxy inserted in front of the browser.  The end user with privileged access to their own computer has the ability to see their own stuff.  You can't prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding requests under network tab is not advisable. Instead you can secure your request data using some sort of encryption library like bcrypt. with the help of libraries like this you can encrypt your passowrd before sending it to the server, that way you wont be exposing sensitive data to other people. And on server side you can decrypt the data again using the same library.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible as far as I'm aware. Most of the dev tools built into chrome are not able to be manipulated by the browser. This would be to ensure a level of integrity between the user and the website. If you could hide network requests it would be catastrophic, allowing a website to send anything in the background without you knowing.

**Facebook** also sends your data through to the server in plaintext form. 
[image: Facebook Example]
[Pausible Gif](https://i.gyazo.com/710add802d05336733d9920d07ce64ed.mp4)

Because of this functionality VPNs exist to encrypt the payload when going to the server. This is the data/network request that people intercept on public wifi's to gain your information (A brief explanation, research more if you're interested)