# Hide api using expressjs and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

I'm using MERN stack for a project. I want to hide my api endpoints on the frontend when I call them. I'm now making a request from React like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://MY_API_URL/posts") // MY_API_URL is the url that I want to hide
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(res.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

This is how I'm `GET`ing the posts from the expressjs:
`controllers/posts.js`

```
const Post = require("../models/post");

const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.find();
    res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

I want to make the request to the url from the backend so that my API is hidden in the client.
This is what I have tried in the frontend:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/posts")
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(res.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

And my backend now looks like this but it doesn't work. I also have removed the `Posts.find()` inside the request, I'm not sure if it is still necessary or how am I going to use this?
`controllers/posts.js`

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://MY_API_URL/posts"
    );
    const posts = response.data;
    console.log(posts);
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

On localhost it works fine, but when I push my code to github and deploy it, it doesn't work on the deployed version then in the localhost it also stops working.
Error message on console:
`GET http://localhost:3000/posts 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: you can make the request to the url from the frontend and keep your url hidden. all you need to do is put your url inside .env file and provide it inside your app

Comment: @amiryeganeh have already read about that method but it is not totally hidden. If you hide it in the client side and put it in .env in client, it only won't push to github but you still can see it in the devtools.

Comment: yes, that's right I didn't know that!. I searched, and it looks impossible to do it on the front end. but maybe this answer gives you some idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/58073798/13152776

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help since I'm trying to hide the URL from the code not from the request